# Multiple operations in Knex transaction

Tags: knex.js

I have five (5) operations to do on database within one function. I want to put them into transaction, but I find a bit strange to put each one in a callback of the previous operation. How can I do it in elegant and readable fashion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knex is has a built-in transaction support, it looks like this:

```js
await knex.transaction(async trx => {
    await knex('users')
      .insert({id: 1, username: 'foo'})
      .transacting(trx);

    await knex('members')
      .insert({userId: 1})
      .transacting(trx);
  });
```

Comment: Bless you! In their docs they only show promise based example with two operations only. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

A bit simpler version. `.transacting()` is actually pretty much never needed since you can build queries which should go to the same transaction directly using `trx` instead of `knex`.

```
await knex.transaction(async trx => {
    await trx('users').insert({id: 1, username: 'foo'});
    await trx('members').insert({userId: 1});
});
```

Comment: I wonder where you guys get to learn that when docs don't say a word about those (great btw) solutions :) Another good one!

Comment: I've been using knex over 5 years and I've been also maintaining it most of that time... knowledge has been built from reading code and years of trying out and fixing things and solving issues in github. I suppose that right now problem with transaction documentation is that there are so many ways to use transactions that people get confused and that examples are using promises instead of async / await... If you are able to clarify knex documentation there is knex/documentation repo where PRs are welcome :)

Comment: Great idea! Just pushed `pull request`: https://github.com/knex/documentation/pull/247